# How do I install Microsoft Edge on FreeBSD?

Tags: installation, freebsd, microsoft-edge

I would like to use MSEdge on FreeBSD, but it's not on pkg, how do I install it?

Comment: Have you tried this article?  https://itsfoss.com/microsoft-edge-linux/

Comment: You can't directly. Edge is a exe thing. You need to use wine if you want to use it badly. But it is not recommended.

Comment: @SohanArafat edge is available on linux

Comment: Is free bsd debian based? Then you can download it and install https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge

Comment: @SohanArafat FreeBSD is FreeBSD. Not a linux distro

Comment: Sorry , wrong dept.

Answer (score -1):

What comes to mind for me is using Wine: https://wiki.freebsd.org/Wine and https://www.winehq.org/

It has been a very long time since I have even tried to use Wine, but I did hear, somewhere, that it has gotten better since I have used it.

I also came across this from github, that might be helpful: https://github.com/mrclksr/linux-browser-installer

Comment: Doesn't FreeBSD have binary compatibility with linux? If so can't I just run the linux version?